# How to get several values from the same it.next()

Tags: java, arrays, iterator

```
List<Drank> dranken = admin.getBestelling().getDranken();
Iterator<Drank> it = dranken.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
     String name = it.next().getName();
     String description = it.next().getDescription();   
     model.addRow(new Object[]{name,description});
}
```

This is our code. We want to loop through the array. 
The problem is that if you use `it.next()` it always goes to the next value, and because we have `getName()` and `getDescription()` it always skips either the name or the description, making value's not match with each other,

any suggestions?

Comment: it#next() goes to pic next values. you need Drank darnk= it.next(); then access your object drank.getName(); drank.getgetDescription()

Comment: @bhutto This is an answer, no matter how short it is, it's not a comment ;)

Comment: Who downvoted this? Care to comment?

Comment: @Joffrey Yeah i Know this is answer. so what the problem with short answer with comments

Comment: @bhutto Look at the "When shouldn't I comment?" section there: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment

Comment: Stop changing my variables in "drunken"......how childiss

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a variable to store the next element.

```
 Drank next = it.next();
 String name = next.getName();
 String description = next.getDescription();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `it.next()` only once, and get the result in a `Drank` variable, as @user1906108 shew you.

Alternatively, you can use the enhanced `for` loop, and totally get rid of the iterator's code:

```
ArrayList<Drank> dranken = admin.getBestelling().getDranken();

for (Drank d : dranken) {
     String name = d.getName();
     String description = d.getDescription();   
     model.addRow(new Object[]{name,description});
}
```

Or even shorter, as you don't really need extra variables here:

```
ArrayList<Drank> dranken = admin.getBestelling().getDranken();

for (Drank d : dranken) {
     model.addRow(new Object[]{ d.getName(), d.getDescription()});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change it to this

```
while (it.hasNext()) {
     Drank item = it.next();
     String name = item.getName();
     String description = item.getDescription();   
     model.addRow(new Object[]{name,description});
}
```